# Javascript function is not terminating on given conditional

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I Have the function below to solve a problem on Hackerrank [Chocolate feast](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/chocolate-feast) but it seems to work well but it goes in for an extra loop instead of terminating ending up giving me undefined. What am I missing any help will be appreciated `

```
function main() {
var t = parseInt(readLine());
for(var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    var n_temp = readLine().split(' ');
    var n = parseInt(n_temp[0]);//amount
    var c = parseInt(n_temp[1]);//cost
    var m = parseInt(n_temp[2]);//number of wrappers recquired

    var bought = Math.floor(n/c);
    var count = 0;
    var extra = swapWrap(bought);
    var arr = new Array(); 

    function swapWrap(x){
        var freeChocolates = 0;
       if(x >= m){
           count += Math.floor(x/m);
            freeChocolates = Math.floor(x/m);//chocolates I get after swapping 
            var remaining = x%m + freeChocolates;//remaining chocolate wrapper + free chocolate wrapper

           swapWrap(remaining); //recurse
       }else{
           return count;
       }

    }

   console.log(extra);
}
```

}

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would "terminate" the for loop ?

Comment: don't declare functions inside a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing recursion, you might want to add a return to this line

```
return swapWrap(remaining); //recurse
```